# PDO - using same query for multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have two foreach loops in my code that use the same query, so I was wondering if I could just make the query at the beginning of the page and just call it later in the code so I only have to access the database once.  I tried this and the first loop went through but the second one did not.  Is there a way to only query once but use it in two foreach loops?  This is what I thought might be the answer:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM champs WHERE $role = '1' ORDER BY id";
if (!empty($role)) {
$champs = $db->query($sql);
}
```

*Some HTML*

```
if (!empty($role)) {
foreach($champs as $row) {
     echo   '<div class = "champion_left">
     <p>'.$row['name'].'
      <img class = "face_left" src = "images/small/'.$row['name'].'.png">
      <div class = "name" onmouseover="if(champ1==\'\') preview1(\''.$row['name'].'\', \''.$row['name'].'\')" onmouseout="if(champ1==\'\')restoreAvatar1()" onClick="champ1 = \''.$row['name'].'\'; preview1(\''.$row['name'].'\', \''.$row['name'].'\')">
      </div>
     </p>
    </div>';
}
}
```

*Some more HTML*

```
if (!empty($role)) {
foreach($champs as $row) {
     echo   '<div class = "champion_right">
     <p>'.$row['name'].'
      <img class = "face_right" src = "images/small/'.$row['name'].'.png">
      <div class = "name" onmouseover="if(champ2==\'\') preview2(\''.$row['name'].'\', \''.$row['name'].'\')" onmouseout="if(champ2==\'\')restoreAvatar2()" onClick="champ2 = \''.$row['name'].'\'; preview2(\''.$row['name'].'\', \''.$row['name'].'\')">
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>';
}
}
```

Comment: Define *not work*. Have you check `var_dump($champs);` before your second loop. Are you using `$champs` after first & before second loop anywhere ?

Comment: @Rikesh not work as in no results show up when it should be the same results as the first loop.  And no, `$champs` is not used anywhere else in the code.  Also, `var_dump` shows `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(51) "SELECT * FROM champs WHERE middle = '1' ORDER BY id" }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM champs WHERE $role = '1' ORDER BY id";
    if (!empty($role)) {
            $champs = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

This will convert your results to an array which you can use as  you like. Also you must check for `isset($champs)` or `!empty($champs)` before using it.